# How do I ensure autocomplete works for a specific field?

Tags: html, cross-browser

How do browsers recognize if a particular field (like a username) should be prompted with autocompletes? Do they use some sort of regex to match the fields `name` attribute? Is there a standard I need to follow to ensure this?

I ask this because on some sites the browser fails to suggest any historical data.

Put simply, I am asking the **exact opposite** of what this person was trying to achieve:

[How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Depending on the browser, either the `name` or `id` attribute is used as a key to historical data. For example if you fill out and submit a form with `<input type='text' id='email' />` and you then navigate to another site with `<input type='text' id='email' />` then depending on your browser settings, it should autocomplete with historical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience it's based on matching the name or id attribute of the input tag. Which is why you generally find that username, email and name fields tend to autocomplete on a number of different websites.

I think the matching has to be exact, not a regex or partial match on the field.

Comment: regex is in the house!  Try entering co  and see all the .com email addresses that you have ever entered.

Answer (score 2):

With HTML5:

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" autocomplete="on">
 First name:<input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
 E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" /><br />
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_autocomplete.asp

Comment: Or this link http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/#the-autocomplete. Might as well visit http://w3fools.com/.

Comment: Haha, they always come up first on Google. Must have some killer SEO specialists. Here is a jsFiddle with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/y6TFt/